# ¿como especificar el tipo de una variable en python?

Tags: python, vscode

estoy usando vscode con python, el problema es que el intellisense no reconoce el tipo de una variable y me dice que es "any" y por eso no me recomienda los metodos ni atibutos de la variable. yo se de antemano que tipo debe ser la variable y mi pregunta es si hay alguna manera de especificarle el tipo a la variable?

si fuera en c# yo haria algo como esto:

```
object x = "Hola";
(x as string).ToLower();
```

Comment: `x: str = "hola"` esa sintaxis esta disponible a partir de python 3.5

Comment: Aparte de que puedas expresar explícitamente el tipo, pylance hace un notable esfuerzo para inferir los tipos analizando el código fuente de los módulos que utilices. En cuando hagas uso de la variable le darás pistas a pylance para averiguar su tipo.

Answer (score 1):

Hola en python no se especifica la variable ya que lo detecta automáticamente por ejemplo te dejare tipos de variables

Ejemplo:

```
Nombre = Felipe

N_float = 10.50

N_int = 80
```

y así sucesivamente, se asigna automáticamente ahora si quieres saber el tipo de valor que tiene la variable colocas la función type() un ejemplo:

```
Nombre = Felipe

print(type(Nombre))
```

espero haberte ayudado saludos !

Comment: Felipe no debería ir entre comillas? De todas formas esta respuesta no es correcta. Python si que tiene sintaxis para la declaración de tipos estáticos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes especificar el tipo de una variable así:

```
x:str
```

pero en muchos casos no es necesario porque el analizador de tipos puede descubrirlo según cómo la inicialices. Por tanto también puedes hacer:

```
x = ""
```

Si lo inicializas recogiendo el resultado de una función, así:

```
x = mi_func()
```

entonces el motor de tipos podrá deducir el tipo de `x` según el tipo de retorno declarado para esa función. Aquí es donde puede salirte eso de `Any`  si la función no declara el tipo retornado y no es posible deducirlo.

Para declarar el tipo retornado la sintaxis sería:

```
def mi_func() -> str:
  return "Hola"
```

pero en un caso como este ejemplo no sería necesario, ya que puede deducirse del tipo usado en el `return`

Puedes aprender más sobre la declaración de tipos en python en [su documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) y sobre todo en el [PEP483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/) o en el [manual de mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html) (una herramienta de comprobación estática de tipos)

**Nota**. Los tipos que declares no tienen efecto en tiempo de ejecución. Es decir, puedes declarar que una variable es `str` y en cambio asignarle un entero, sin que el programa vaya a producir ningún error al ejecutarse. Para el intérprete los tipos son meros comentarios. Quien los usa es el editor para sugerirte autocompletados o subrayarte en rojo errores de tipo. También herramientas como `mypy` que pueden analizar tu código a modo de "compilador" para señalarte inconsistencias de tipo. Algunas librerías como Pydantic o FastAPI también acceden a la información de tipos para generar chequeos en tiempo de ejecución, documentación automática, validación de parámetros recibidos por red o por json, etc. Es un campo muy interesante y relativamente nuevo (disponible desde python 3.5)